# Use a variable inside PowerShell command's parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a variable named `$blockSize` and i want to replace it with `5` in the following command:

```
rar a fileName SomeDir -v5M -r
```

I have tried `rar a  fileName SomeDir -v$blockSizeM -r` but it doesn't work

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7 . Info is readily available on the web

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Expression "rar a fileName SomeDir -v$blockSizeM -r"
```

or safer:

```
$archivePath = 'c:\temp\file.rar'
$blockSize = 10
$rarPath = 'c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe'
$args = ('a {0} SomeDir -v{1}M -r' -f $archivePath, $blockSize)
Start-Process -FilePath $rarPath -ArgumentList $args -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

More info:

- [Invoke-Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7)
- [Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7)